# How to serialize an "Object" type in PHP to be sent to a WCF Service?

Tags: php, wcf, object, serialization

My WCF Service can accept a request to update a field dynamically by passing the value wrapped in an Object and a DynamicAttributeType enum to specify the type, like so:

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
[KnownType(typeof(bool))]
[KnownType(typeof(PickListInfo))]
public class DynamicAttributeInfo
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public object Value { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public DynamicAttributeType DynamicAttributeType { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine for .Net clients. I'm trying to help a PHP client make it work. So far we're having trouble with creating something that will pass as Object but still contain the true value inside (string/bool/PickList).

**Please note:** the WCF service is in production and changing it is not an option. I'm looking for a solution for the PHP client.

Here are his different attempts:

1) First try - simple string as value:

```php
<?php
   $da = new DynamicAttributeInfo();
   $da->DynamicAttributeType = 'String';
   $da->Name = 'lv_eutmsource';
   $da->Value = 'test';
?>
```

exception:
 [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                                 (
                                     [HelpLink] =>
                                     [InnerException] =>
                                     [Message] => End element 'Value' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.XXX.XXXService.Common.Entities' expected. Found text 'test'. Line 2, position 725.

2) Second take (semi-successful): a new object of empty class

```php
<?php
 class testText() {
 }

 $da = new DynamicAttributeInfo();
 $da->DynamicAttributeType = 'String';
 $da->Name = 'lv_eutmsource';
 $da->Value = new testText();
?>
```

There was no WCF exception this time, but no value was actually passed and my code ended up with "Object.ToString".

3) Other attempts: non-empty classes - he tried to add fields with different names - nothing worked.

```php
<?php
 class Value() {
     public $String;
 }

 $text = new Value();
 $text->String = 'test text';

 $da = new DynamicAttributeInfo();
 $da->DynamicAttributeType = 'String';
 $da->Name = 'lv_eutmsource';
 $da->Value = $text;
?>
```

exception:
 [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                         (
                             [HelpLink] =>
                             [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                                 (
                                     [HelpLink] =>
                                     [InnerException] =>
                                     [Message] => End element 'Value' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.XXX.XXXService.Common.Entities' expected. Found element 'String' from namespace ''.

```php
<?php
 class textText() {
     public $text;
 }

 $text = new testText();
 $text->text = 'test text';

 $da = new DynamicAttributeInfo();
 $da->DynamicAttributeType = 'String';
 $da->Name = 'lv_eutmsource';
 $da->Value = $text;
?>
```

exception:
 [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                         (
                             [HelpLink] =>
                             [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                                 (
                                     [HelpLink] =>
                                     [InnerException] =>
                                     [Message] => End element 'Value' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.XXX.XXXService.Common.Entities' expected. Found element 'text' from namespace ''.

```php
<?php
 class Value() {
     public $Value;
 }

 $text = new Value();
 $text->Value = 'test text';

 $da = new DynamicAttributeInfo();
 $da->DynamicAttributeType = 'String';
 $da->Name = 'lv_eutmsource';
 $da->Value = $text;
?>
```

exception:
 [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                         (
                             [HelpLink] =>
                             [InnerException] => stdClass Object
                                 (
                                     [HelpLink] =>
                                     [InnerException] =>
                                     [Message] => End element 'Value' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.XXX.XXXService.Common.Entities' expected. Found element 'Value' from namespace ''.

Comment: You obviously got the connection to the WCF service working, but you should add how you are actually serializing your objects. Also, have you analysed the serialized output and compared it with the specifications from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my client was able to make it work after all. Here's how:

Instead of plainly assigning value to the field, as i usually did:

```
$DynamicAttributeInfo->Value = $text;
```

I had to manually create a SOAP variable explicitly defining it's type and namespace:

```
$DynamicAttributeInfo->Value = new SoapVar($text,XSD_STRING,'string','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
```

and this way it passes as expected.