# Error when calling WCF function with two arguments

Tags: c#, php, wcf

My WCF service have method that accepts two parameters. In object browers this method looks like

```
public wcfelmaservice.racun SendOrder(wcfelmaservice.order Order_Header, System.Collections.Generic.List<order_items> Order_Items)
```

Order_Header have two members:

```
public string Number { set; get; }
public string Name { set; get; }
```

Order_Items have these members:

```
public decimal Price { set; get; }
public decimal Qty { set; get; }
public string ItemName { set; get; }
```

Now I have to pass values from PHP to WCF service. I'm doing it on this way:

```
<?php
$wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost:28309/Service1.svc?wsdl');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
//var_dump($wcfClient->__getFunctions());

$header = new StdClass;
$header->Number="1";
$header->Name="Test d.o.o";


$item = new StdClass;
$item->Price = "10.00";
$item->Qty="5";
$item->ItemName="SomeItemName";


$paramHeader = array ('Order_Header' => $header);
$paramItems = array ('Order_Items' => $item);


$response = $wcfClient->SendOrder($paramHeader, $paramsItems);

?>
```

When I run this script i get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed]
>   The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'SendOrder'. End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but your WCF method's signature has a single instance of `Order_Header` and a collection of `Order_Item`, and in your script your passing in an array of `Order_Header`.  Try passing in just the single instance of `Order_Header` and see if that works.  `$response = $wcfClient->SendOrder($header, $paramsItems);`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not my forte, but a quick search on SO and I found this: [How to serialize an "Object" type in PHP to be sent to a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180579/how-to-serialize-an-object-type-in-php-to-be-sent-to-a-wcf-service).  Hope that helps.